# Ktor HttpClient Mock Fails

Tags: ktor

I'm trying to create a Ktor (1.3.1) HttpClient Mock with JsonFeature like this:

```
@Test
fun mockFailure() = runBlocking {
    val mock = MockEngine { call ->
        respond("{}",
                HttpStatusCode.OK,
                headersOf("Content-Type", ContentType.Application.Json.toString()))
    }

    val client = HttpClient(mock) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
        }
    }

    val resp =  client.get<JsonObject>("dsf")
}
```

It appears to process it correctly, but then I get this error:

```
io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class kotlinx.coroutines.io.ByteBufferChannel -> class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject
with response from http://localhost/dsf:
status: 200 OK
response headers: 
Content-Type: application/json


    at io.ktor.client.call.HttpClientCall.receive(HttpClientCall.kt:79)
```

Comment: I have opened and issue on the Ktor project: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1676

Comment: seems to be a problem of the serializer, did you try to pass a non empty json?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing client content negotiation plugin in the HttpClient block:

```
val client = HttpClient(mock) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
        }
        //Here
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
            })
        }
}
```

Required dependencies `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")`

Json Serialization `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")`

Also change the last line to `val resp =  client.get<JsonObject>("dsf").body()`